# Make div scrollable depending on its child

Tags: css, css-selectors

I have tables that has large width, so I'm trying to make all divs that contain those tables scrollable as following :

```
div.ui-widget-content:has(table){
    overflow: auto;
}
```

Unfurtunately this didn't work, I don't know why, since I'm using the latest version of chrome (`54.0.2840.99`) which supports CSS4 selectors, and it has to work depending on this website : http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has

I know how it's done using the has method in jQuery, but I need this to be done using only CSS.

When I force `overflow: auto;` in the developer tools, it works, so, the problem resides in the selector I'm using, as you can see in this picture :

[image]

So how can I solve this ?

Comment: [**This**](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-has) link tells that `:has` selector is not supported in any browser till now.

Comment: You may need to turn on experimental features in Chrome. Go to this url: chrome://flags and then 'Enable experimental Web Platform features' and then restart Chrome...

Comment: Also, the link you sent states that it _isn't_ compatible...

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no such thing as CSS4 or the :has() pseudo-class.

It is true that certain CSS modules are at Level4, but that is not the same as a CSS4.

Also, the :has() pseudo-class very likely won't be implemented due to 'logistical reasons' (CSS goes DOWN the tree of elements, visualising elements in that order - :has() would force it to have to go "backwards" (up the tree), which would mean far more resource consumption).

I'm afraid JS (/jQuery) is the way you'll have to go about it.
Something like:

```
$("div").has("table").css("overflow","auto");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you gave the divs that have tables a class unique to those divs, you could set overflow: auto on that specific class. Something like this:

```
<div class="ui-widget-content contains-table">
{your table here}
</div>
```

Then set overflow: auto on the .contains-table class.